# gsp link to put named parameters and map in the same params attribute

Tags: java, grails, gsp

I am getting problem in adding the named argument and map in the same params attribute in `g:link`.

I can put named argument such as:

```
<g:link action="action" controller="controller" params='[hello:"hello",world:"world"]'>test</g:link>
```

or I can make the map in the controller and use that in gsp link params such as:

```
<g:link action="action" controller="controller" params='${testParam}'>test</g:link>
```

This both form the link in proper manner. But now I want to use both ways in the same link inside params attribute such as:

```
<g:link action="action" controller="controller" params='${testMapParam},[hello:"hello",world:"world"]'>test</g:link>
```

I am unable to do in this way. This don't make the proper link. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try `params="[hello:"hello",world:"world"]"` or  `params="${[hello:"hello",world:"world"]}"`

Comment: @vahid sorry, but this doesn't work. I need both the map and named parameter in the same params link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you really can't beat simplicty:

```
def test() {
    def map1=['a':1]
    def map2=['a2':2]

    def map3=map1+map2
    println "000 ${map3} vs ${params}"

    render  view:'test', model:[map1:map1,map2:map2]
}
```

Passing the maps to the view gsp:

```
   <g:set var="map6" value="${[hello1:'hello2',world1:'world2'] }"/>
<g:set var="currentParams" value="${params}"/>
${map1 } ${map6}
<g:link action="test" controller="test" params="${map1+map6+map2+currentParams}">test</g:link>
```

Shows this when I click on link
{a=1} {hello1=hello2, world1=world2} test

My url upon clicking is:

```
/test?a=1&hello1=hello2&world1=world2&a2=2&hello=hello&world=world
000 [a:1, a2:2] vs [hello:hello, a:1, a2:2, world1:world2, hello1:hello2, world:world, action:test, controller:test]
```

What you are trying to do ? no